# What is the easiest way to use Toast in an Android MVVM design pattern?

Tags: android

When I want to use Toast with MVVM,

In ViewModel

```
public MutableLiveData<String> setToast(){

    return ToTo;

}

public void ShowToast(String t){

    ToTo.postValue(t);

}
```

Put the code in this way.

In View

```
model.setToast().observe(this, ob_toast ->{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ob_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

});
```

I used to coding like this.

Whenever I need it, I call the function 'ShowToast' from the ViewModel and write it.
but I don't know if this is right.

need to create a class of Util functions?

I wonder if there is a pattern or a way to use it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to not put *Toast* in your *ViewModel* class because **it's an improper way to put *context* related stuff into *ViewModel***.
Instead you can observe MutableLiveData variables in a context class (Fragment or Activity) and there generate and show your Toast depending on values from MutableLiveData.